# view inside tool bar not getting clicked

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my app I'm using a `Toolbar`. Now in inside my Toolbar I have two `ImageViews`. When the user clicks on any of the ImageViews I open different `Fragment` or `Activity` but in my case I'm not able to click on any of the ImageViews.

***.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_home_about_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/about" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_home_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_home_about_us"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/search" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        style="@style/text_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Trending around me" />

    <com.techmorphosis.wheretoday.SlidingTabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Complete Code**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screen, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        if (!bundle.isEmpty()) {
            position = bundle.getInt(FROM_WHERE_ERROR_OCCURED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        latitude = SettingPreffrences.getLatitude(contextFrag);
        longitude = SettingPreffrences.getLongitude(contextFrag);

        if (latitude.equals("") && longitude.equals("")) {
            commonFunctions.isLocationAvailable();
            commonFunctions.replaceFragment(getActivity(), new ErrorFrag().newInstance(100, 0), false);
        } else {
            initialize();
        }
    }

    private void initialize() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        ivAboutUs = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.iv_home_about_us);
        ivSearch = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.iv_home_search);


        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        tabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        tabLayout.setViewPager(pager);

        if (position == 0) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
        }

        ivAboutUs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(contextFrag, "Yess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ivSearch.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.iv_home_about_us:
                commonFunctions.replaceFragment(getActivity(), new AboutUsFrag(), false);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_home_search:
                Intent intent = new Intent(contextFrag, SearchScreen.class);
                contextFrag.startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

    }
}


class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new TodayFrag();

        }

        if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new TommorowFrag();
        }

        if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new LaterFrag();
        }
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think inside of fragment `ivAboutUs.setOnClickListener(this);` doesn't work don't know why. Try `ivAboutUs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the UI element in `onCreateView` method - EVER

Use `onActivityCreated` method , that tell the fragment the activity is fully created and ready to interact.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ImageView ivAboutUs = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_home_about_us);
    ivAboutUs .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                            }
                    });
}
```

Comment: Sir it is in onActivityCreated()

Comment: Have you tried to find ImageView for `view` instead of `toolbar`?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue where the touch events never reach the ImageViews because they were absorbed by something else. I ran into something similar where I was trying to put an onClickListener on an Imageview embedded in a list item. No matter how much I clicked on the imageView, something else was eating up the touch events(Most likely the View that makes up the ListView Item. I fixed the problem by changing the ImageView to an ImageButton and setting its background to null (So that the imageButton would look like an imageView and not an image button.) Once I did that, clicking the images worked for me. Try changing your ImageViews to look like this:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/iv_home_about_us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/about" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_home_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_home_about_us"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.